# ipad onscreen keyboard stop working

Tags: ipad, keyboard, focus

I am working on one of my company's product. It is a focus lost issue. We are using iframes, in this particular page when we touch/click outside input box/ textarea, then onscreen keyboard get disable. This issue comming on all ipads and both browsers Safari & Chrome. We are not able to figure out this issue. It will a gr8 help for us, if you had gone through smilar kind of issue, pls share your experience.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing anything. Check if you have a correct matching label for your textarea. Try disabling javascript and see what happen, maybe some touch or mouse events are active.